# Cursor 'order by' SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I display data from a query on my database in a `ListView`. My question is: Can I order my data from the query, then store this ordered data in my cursor object? Or do I have to order the `ListView`?

i.e can I order the data by name in the following query?

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + passId, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Sure: enumerated SQL results can be ordered (and a cursor can only navigate said result). Just make sure to *not use* ordering in the view/adapter ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last parameter in your query represents [order by](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Example:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + passId, null, null, null, coulmnName+" DESC");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

Added in API level 1
Query the given table, returning a Cursor over the result set.

Parameters
table   The table name to compile the query against.
columns A list of which columns to return. Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data from storage that isn't going to be used.
selection   A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.
selectionArgs   You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear in the selection. The values will be bound as Strings.
groupBy A filter declaring how to group rows, formatted as an SQL GROUP BY clause (excluding the GROUP BY itself). Passing null will cause the rows to not be grouped.
having  A filter declare which row groups to include in the cursor, if row grouping is being used, formatted as an SQL HAVING clause (excluding the HAVING itself). Passing null will cause all row groups to be included, and is required when row grouping is not being used.
orderBy How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default sort order, which may be unordered.
limit   Limits the number of rows returned by the query, formatted as LIMIT clause. Passing null denotes no

Comment: @Nambari Thank you. I knew the ORDER BY clause had to go in there, just wasnt sure if it could actually be done in the cursor. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you very much for that! Thats a great little snippet of info. And after playing around with the nulls on the other clauses it all works.